# postfix logs missing (freebsd)

Tags: postfix, email-server, freebsd

I'm trying to debug an unfamiliar mail server and I can't find any logs for postfix. In the documentation it says:

```
Postfix logs all failed and successful deliveries to a logfile. The file is usually called `/var/log/maillog` or `/var/log/mail`; the exact pathname is defined in the `/etc/syslog.conf`.
```

I checked `/etc/syslog.conf` and it listed `/var/log/maillog` but there is nothing there. The previous admin disabled all logging in other applications and I think it might be the same here. Is there a way I can reenable logging so I can continue to debug?

Edit: As requested when I run `postconf syslog_facility` it returns `syslog_facility = mail`.

My syslog daemon is `syslogd` and I've verified it is running using the command `/usr/sbin/syslogd -l /var/run/log -l /var/named/var/run/log -s`. I've pasted the `syslog.conf` below (removing commented lines):

```
*.err;kern.warning;auth.notice;mail.crit        /dev/console
*.notice;authpriv.none;kern.debug;lpr.info;mail.crit;news.err   /var/log/messages
security.*                  /var/log/security
auth.info;authpriv.info             /var/log/auth.log
mail.info                   /var/log/maillog
lpr.info                    /var/log/lpd-errs
ftp.info                    /var/log/xferlog
cron.*                      /var/log/cron
*.=debug                    /var/log/debug.log
*.emerg                     *
!ppp
*.*                     /var/log/ppp.log
!*
```

Comment: Please show the output of "postconf syslog_facility" and paste it here together with the content of your syslog.conf. Btw: What syslog-daemon do you use? Have you verified it is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All postfix logs should (by default) go into `/var/log/mail.log` (and similar for errors).
Authentication logs should go to `/var/log/auth.log`.

And that could be all, I assume.

Comment: I have an auth.log but no mail.log. Is this something that can be overridden in config?

Comment: According to your syslog.conf all mail should go to /var/log/maillog (as is stated on the fifth line of the config file). And there you can override default settings and specify your own configs.